# Regex Issue getting particular string word from file name

Tags: regex

`Facebook Instagram WhatApps Data_5421-9-41491_112018_12102018 (3).txt.gz`

`Facebook Instagram WhatApps Data_5421-9-41491_112018_12102018.txt.gz`

So these are file names above, so i need regex which only picks 112018 part from the file names above. Is there any way this can be done using regex?

Comment: Welcome! Will the string you want always be the last string of numbers not in parenthesis before the extension?

Comment: Can you post any of your initial attempts?

Comment: @JacobFord   i need these value 112018 to be return from seeing those 2 files names i provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

`^.*_(.*)_.*$`

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/3rgOjH/1)

If you want to be more precise go for this:

`^.*_(\d{6})_.*$`

- ^ - starts with
- .* - any number of characters. Will be greedy. So goes for last two _ _
- _ - specifically this character.
- $ - end with
- \d{6} - 6 digits.
- What is in brackets is known as a capture group - so this is the only part that is returned. See screenshot. Had you followed link @Datafeed11 - you would have seen it works. Group 1...

[image]

Comment: Its doesnt work need only 112018 from that filename others not care.

Comment: @Datafeed11 It works. Group 1! What language are you developing in?

Comment: I am calculation in tableau

Comment: Then tag the question with that too - because for any normal language - Java, Python, JavaScript etc it would work.

Comment: Thanks you answer is more accurate it works in tableau but in notepad++ it wont work

Comment: `_\d{6}_ `is about as close as you can get with Notepad++ - you'd have to post-process it to strip out the _ on either side.

Comment: How about this in Notepad++? Find `(.*_)(\d{6})(_.*)` Replace `\2` You have 3 capture groups - drop first and third and replace with second.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work : `((?:0|1)\d20(?:0|1|2)\d)`

`(?:0|1)\d` for month
`20(?:0|1|2)\d` for year

Format MMYYYY

correct answer: (?!*)(\d{6})(?=*)

Comment: So this wont work because it selects 2 dates parts. i only need 112018 for my one i dont need anything else in that filename

Comment: This regex will select only the 6 digit date parts

Comment: but if you see file name they have 112018_12102018 but i dont need anything else after 112018 i only need that as my final value

Comment: So i have 100 files names like this so according this way it will pick 2 dates like 112018 and 102018 because it has 2 dates on filenames. i only MMYYYY of first one thats it all time it should go to next one

Comment: How do you know if that's Nov 2018 or 20th Nov 18 - you presume too much.

Comment: Okay, no problem